# Select Cells with Value Greater than Zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of values and I want to select the cells that are greater than 0:

[image: Example]

I tried looking online but could not find a solution.  How can I do this with a VBA script, preferably without writing a loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i&, arr() As Long, rng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ReDim arr(0)
    Call nonZeroSelection(ActiveSheet, i, arr, rng)

End Sub

Sub nonZeroSelection(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef i&, ByRef arr() As Long, rng As Range)
    Dim lr&, ix$
    lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lr
        Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i)
            If rng.Value = "0" Then
                ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
                arr(UBound(arr) - 1) = i
            End If
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        ix = ix & arr(i) & ":" & arr(i) & ","
    Next i
    ix = Left(ix, Len(ix) - 1)
    ws.Range(ix).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx#BMfilter_numbers). Add an extra line above `A1`, create a Filter and Filter out `0`. No VBA needed :)

You can also create a [custom filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/all-about-autofilter-RZ001145981.aspx?section=8).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I want to use a VBA script to do it because it's part of an automated process.  The range will be passed on to another function.

Comment: Ooh, well what about doing that while recording a macro. Should give you a good start to work with.

Comment: this link from Ozgrid could help: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm

Comment: @mchangun you can do the filter using VBA, or use **SpecialCells** as in my answer

Answer (score 1):

or another column (column **B** here but *could be any column*) and **SpecialCells** function

```
Sub selectCells()

Dim sFormula As String
Dim lLastRow As Long

lLastRow = Rows(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sFormula = "=IF(A:A>0,NA(),"""")"

With Range("B1:B" & lLastRow)
    .Formula = sFormula
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Offset(0, -1).Select
    .clear
End With

End Sub
```

so this accomplishes what you want *without a loop* but similar to **Filter**